# Balanced Random Assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, random, matrix, numpy

It has been a *very* long time since I've used Python.

**What I'm looking for**: I would like to create a 6-by-6 random matrix where each component is either 1 or 2, **so that there are 18 ones and 18 twos**.

**Attempt**:

```
import numpy
import random

array = numpy.zeros((6, 6))
while (array == 1).sum() != 18 or (array == 2).sum() != 18: 
    for i in range(0, 6):
        for j in range(0, 6):
            array[i][j] = random.randint(1, 2) 
print array
```

Sure, this works. But this seems to me to be *extremely* inefficient, as the code is literally having to insert new matrix values until the number of ones/twos is 18. How can I make this more efficient?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just create a list of 18 ones and 18 twos, shuffle it, then reshape to 6x6:

```
from random import shuffle
from numpy import reshape

nums = [1]*18 + [2]*18
shuffle(nums)
arr = reshape(nums, (6, 6))
```

Produces (for example):

```
array([[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]])
```